# XSLT: How to access elements of type both namespace and without namespaces within same article

Tags: xslt-2.0

Please suggest to access the elements which are not having any namespaces. However my code able to access and alter the nodes (elements) which are having namespaces. I am using XSLT2 version. Find my xml (I used DTD path mapped to my local path, please suggest also for access the XML without DTD help.

InPut XML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE article PUBLIC "-//ES//DTD journal article DTD version 5.2.0//EN//XML" "D:/DTDs/Els-parser/art520.dtd">
    <article>
    <fm>
        <ce:title>The title</ce:title>
        <ce:author-group>
            <ce:author><ce:surname>Rudramuni</ce:surname><ce:given-names>TP</ce:given-names></ce:author>
        </ce:author-group>
    </fm>
    <body>
        <ce:sections>
            <ce:section>
                <ce:section-title>The first Head</ce:section-title>
                <ce:para>Tha first para</ce:para>
            </ce:section>
        </ce:sections>
    </body>
    <back>
    <ref><ce:author>Vijay</ce:author></ref>
    </back>
</article>
```

XSLT:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:ce="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/common/dtd"
            xmlns:sb="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/common/struct-bib/dtd"
            xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
            xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
            version='2.0'>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
       <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="fm">
     <xsl:element name="ce:front"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="ce:author">
<xsl:element name="name"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Required Result:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<article>
   <ce:front>
    <ce:title>The title</ce:title>
        <ce:author-group><name><ce:surname>Rudramuni</ce:surname><ce:given-names>TP</ce:given-names></name></ce:author-group>
    </ce:front>
    <body><ce:sections><ce:section><ce:section-title>The first Head</ce:section-title><ce:para>Tha first para</ce:para></ce:section></ce:sections></body>
    <back>
    <ref><name>Vijay</name></ref>
    </back>
</article>
```

But I am getting some extra namespaces like "xmlns="http://www.elsevier.com/xml/ja/dtd" and  xmlns="", and some extra attributes are found for some elements like view="all". Thanks in advance. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to ask a lot of questions on XSLT 2.0 recently, which is ok of course, but please kindly consider these guidelines when asking questions:

- Use valid examples that we can reproduce your problem with. Your examples, in this and other questions, are not well-formed (missing namespaces in this question for instance), which makes it hard to help you (and they will downvote or close your question, see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)).
- Tone down the examples to the bare minimum, otherwise people will not run to help you as it is too hard to understand the question asked. In this case, a two-line XML and XSLT would explain your issue.
- Run the code you paste here and copy the output (or errors) you get. In this question for instance, the output is not namespace-well-formed, which cannot possibly be the output of any XSLT processor.

To answer your question, you can use a wild-card NameTest, which selects that name in any namespace:

```
select="*:something" 
select="*:foo/*:bar"
select="*:foo[contains(., @*:some-attr)]"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir, for your advice. I will try to follow your guidelines.

Comment: With your code, now I can access the both namespace and without namespace elements. Thanks for your simple code with perfect results. And one small doubt, is asking more questions is not correct?

Comment: @RudramuniTP: you can ask more questions, that is fine, as long as you ask it as separate questions on SO (I mean, do not put multiple questions in one). So, go ahead and ask all the XSLT-related questions you want ;). Please also read (takes you 5 min): [ask].

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and more for your suggestion towards my question, especially. Thank u...